# Fetch Application Navigator Content from Atlassian JIRA

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-rest-api

I am just browsing through the Atlassian docs for some hours now and still didn't find any hooks for this.

Basically I want to implement the Application Navigator to other internal tools. There is no need to modify them - just display all existing Application Navigator links.

Any idea where/ how I can fetch all entries from the Application Navigator via any API Atlassian provides? We also use Confluence and could use one of the API's this tool provides but I didn't finy any hook there either.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking in my network traffic in Chrome, I see that there is a REST call to get the links in the app switcher. As of the time of this answer (JIRA 7.1), calling `rest/menu/latest/appswitcher` will return JSON of an array of objects, structured like so:

```
[
    {
        key: "home",
        link: "https://jira.company.com/secure/MyJiraHome.jspa",
        label: "JIRA",
        local: false,
        self: true,
        applicationType: "jira"
    },
    {
        key: "home",
        link: "https://confluence.company.com/",
        label: "Confluence",
        local: false,
        self: false,
        applicationType: "confluence"
    },
    {
        key: "home",
        link: "https://something.company.com",
        label: "Custom Web App",
        local: true,
        self: false,
        applicationType: "jira"
    }
]
```

The `menu` API is undocumented, so I rooted around the minified JS to see what I could find out about how this data is used.

- `key` is an identifier, and seems to be unused.
- Obviously, `link` and `label` are the link href and text, respectively.
- `local` does nothing at all, it seems.
- If `self` is true, that just means that it's the currently selected link.
- `applicationType` seems to have something to do with suggesting apps to the user, but it's also not used for building the link list.